# 508 Compliance and Dynamic Web Pages

Tags: html, jaws-screen-reader, section508

*UPDATED*

I am working on a project that has to be 508 compliant. There is a section of the application that has dynamic elements.

For example there is this html:

```
<div id="dynamicDiv"></div>
<select id="selectId"></select>
```

The options for the `select` are populated on the backend from a database. When a user selects an option from the `select` an element is populated into the `dynamicDiv` element. In this case it is a `label`, with the text from the option, and a `button` that when clicked will remove the `label` and `button` from the `dynamicDiv`.

When I test this with JAWS 16 it seems like JAWS is getting "lost" in the DOM. Focus is still on the `select`, but JAWS is reading information off of the elements that was added. Normally it starts reading between the `label` and the `button` that was added to the `dynamicDiv`. When you try to navigate through the `select` with the arrow keys JAWS starts reading like you are moving through the DOM.

The oddest part of all of this is that the `select` continues to have the blue highlight and dotted focused boarder on it. If you can get JAWS to read the contents of the `select` and press enter then the `select` goes back to working (able to navigate through the options in the `select` with the arrow keys) until you select a new thing from the options. Then JAWS gets lost again.

I have tried to force the focus on the `select` but that is not working either. The `select` looks as if it still has focus, but JAWS is reading from the updated `dynamicDiv`. What I am thinking is that the index JAWS is using from the DOM is not being updated. So JAWS thinks that it is on the same element (the `select` in this case), but it is actually pointing to the new elements that have been added to the DOM.

Has anyone ran into this? Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: not sure if jaws 16 supports ajax, but offhand i bet its your markup. selects only take option or optionset. proper markup solves an absurd number of at/a11y compatibility issues. try option and get back to us.

Comment: So the select does use options. They are populated via a database lookup table. When a user selects an option it is removed from the options list and a label and button are added to the div.

Comment: ah, i thought you had the label and button in the select. in this case, i'd say...if they're shown on select, then on select go ahead and disable the select, while passing focus to the elements within the div.

Comment: I want the focus to stay on the select. So a user can add more than one option with out having to tab back to the select. When you add something JAWS moves through the `dynamicDiv` with the arrow keys. The `select` still shows that is has focus (it is still highlighted), but you can not change the selection with the arrow keys.

Comment: pretty hard to id without seeing a working example. offhand, i don't think this is appropriate use of elements...aka why jaws can't follow along. i would look into outputting the new content in an output element, or look into using a datalist instead of the select.

Comment: Thanks @albert I will look into that. I'll also see if I can mock up something similar to what is going on so we can look into it for sure.

Comment: add a tabindex of -1 to the two elements being injected into the dynamic div. i know the select is still focused, but something isn't....maybe that'll throw it back. if that doesn't work...add one to the dynamic div as well. if that doesn't work...ha. yay. come back and report and we'll figure something out. @Chutner23 answer regarding aria could just as easily be a fix. if not the answer, then using aria in and of itself...

Comment: The elements that are being added to the page need to be tabbable. So I can't do the tabindex of -1. That would not make it any better.

Comment: man. i'm about of solutions (that aren't really solutions ;) ) for you...sorry. you may want to give this a bounty or reach out to some a11y pros. i'm very interested/intrigued to hear about your solution when you come to it though. i reckon most a11y minded developers are.

Comment: perhaps asking your question here will help seek a solution https://gitter.im/w3c/a11ySlackers

Answer (score 0):

Is this region surrounded by Aria-Live tags? If so this could be why it gets "lost" because on update of the dom JAWS goes to reading it, but it seems like its getting lost when really its just reading the updated information.

Comment: It does not read it automatically like aria-live tags normally do, so I don't think so. I will look, and get back to you. JAWS only reads when you press the up or down arrow. Like you are trying to select something from the select dropdown, but it starts to read from the `dynaimcDiv`.